# Phoenix different title per page with root module

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

This question is similar to (but not an exact duplicate of) [Phoenix Framework - page titles per route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362376/phoenix-framework-page-titles-per-route).

Ideally, i want to create titles like in the described question, but I am using a root layout since my project uses Phoenix LiveView. The HTML skeleton including the `head` and `title` HTML tag are part of the root template (`root.html.eex`). The app template extends on that from my understanding. I implemented the code from the above question

```html
<title>
  <%= if Kernel.function_exported?(@view_module, :title, 2) do %>
    <%= @view_module.title(Phoenix.Controller.action_name(@conn), assigns) %> - StHub
  <% else %>
    StHub
  <% end %>
</title>
```

and created a title function inside of my specific page view

```
defmodule StHubWeb.WowsView do
  use StHubWeb, :view

  def title(_action, _assigns) do
    "Dashboard"
  end
end
```

but the `else` branch of the code is triggered. Upon further inspection, I think that the issue is with using a root template, because the `@view_module` while rendering the root template is `StHubWeb.LayoutView`, and only inside of the `LayoutView/app.html.eex` template, the `@view_module` is my actual view (`StHubWeb.WowsView`).

I am not sure how to solve this other than removing the root template, but then my LiveView will have to contain the entire HTML skeleton all the time.
Maybe there is a way for me to define a title function in my `LayoutView` that will grab the title from `StHubWeb.WowsView`, but I am not sure how to do that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you seen this: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#module-updating-the-html-document-title

Please note that the question you link to is actually quite old. Phoenix Live View has evolved a lot since then.

Comment: I generated a phoenix 1.5 project with `mix phx.new --live foo` and I see in `lib/foo_web/templates/layout/root.html.leex` there is a `live_title_tag` element which uses `:page_title` on the assigns. You just have to assign this `:page_title` in your live view to get a custom title (in PHoenix 1.5).

Comment: Thanks @PeacefulJames, I have a project where I added live view to after creating the project already, so I didn't have that root template. I would prefer an option where I can export a function somewhere instead of having to assign every time, but that will work for now! thanks!